# How can I extend the AccountController using events rather than inheritance?

Tags: login, event-observer, inheritance, extend

I've successfully extended the core `Mage_Customer_AccountController` via inheritance (using an approach very close to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9350848/60724)), however I'd rather use events to add my extra functionality.

In my case I need to hook in to the request before it's sent to the `loginAction()`, as well as before `_loginPostRedirect()`.

So far I've found mention of an event, `controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_loginPost`, which should be close to what I need for the `_loginPostRedirect()` hook.  I've tried finding the exact point that this event is raised to confirm, but it appears to be a dynamic event which I haven't approached before.

So, to sum up my question, which events would I need to hook into?  And if the `controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_loginPost` is involved, could someone point me to intro resources on dynamic events and their dispatch?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is actually the predispatch rather than postdispatch events unless I am miss understanding your request.

These events can be found in `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch` where right at the bottom you see the following lines of code.

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_action_predispatch', array('controller_action' => $this));
Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_action_predispatch_' . $this->getRequest()->getRouteName(),
    array('controller_action' => $this));
Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_action_predispatch_' . $this->getFullActionName(),
    array('controller_action' => $this));
```